# Add check-box to listview item

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, linked-list

I am creating a iPhone website using jQuery Mobile and Javascript and I am attempting something that doesn't seem to have been attempted before as their are no actual tutorials on it.

I want to add a check-box to a Listview item I have tried to modify every single example that are available on the jQuery website but I can not seem to get the effect I am looking for. Any suggestions

code I have which does not include the 10 million other codes that i have tried

```
<div class="content-primary">   
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="index.html">
                <img src="images/album-bb.jpg" />
                <h3>Broken Bells</h3>
                <p>Broken Bells</p>
            </a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
```

Below is the image to clarify what I want to achieve:
[image]

Comment: where is the code...just make a jsfiddle and add link here...

Comment: @CodeJack so I'm guessing u have no intention of answering the question you only wanted to see if i have code. Please don't waste my time mate.. god.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <div class="content-primary">   
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><input type="checkbox" ><img src="images/album-bb.jpg" style="float:left" />
<a href="index.html">

                    <h3>Broken Bells</h3>
                    <p>Broken Bells</p>
                </a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: I have tried this the check-box display in the mdile of the list view and you cant even check it